use ABP in seperate Web API
I have the following setup:
A standard ABP project with multi-tenancy, where each tenant has its own database.
Additionally, I have a Sync-Library and a Sync-WebAPI project. I need to access the ABP repositories within my Sync-Library.
In the appsettings.json file of the WebAPI, I have the connection string for the Host Database configured as follows:
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Default": "#####"
}.


This is my SyncModule in the Sync-Libary:
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(BackendEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(BackendDomainModule))]
public class SyncModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {

    }
}


In my WebAPI, I initialize it with the following call:
await builder.AddApplicationAsync<SyncModule>();
I also need to work with the database of a specific tenant, so I wrote a middleware to handle this:
public class TenantMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TenantMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ICurrentTenant currentTenant)
    {
        currentTenant.Change(new Guid("8B612708-6465-16A2-C0AB-3A1442DC7C8A"));

        await _next(context);
    }
}

I want to perform the following operation in my Sync-Library:
 var customer = await _customerRepository.SingleAsync(x => x.Number == item.CustomerNumber);
However, I keep encountering this error:
 Error while processing CustomerModel for item c86215b3-cab7-4eb9-89cc-0000003f13c4
      Volo.Abp.AbpException: A DbContext can only be created inside a unit of work!
         at Volo.Abp.Uow.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.GetDbContextAsync()
         at Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreRepository`2.GetDbSetAsync()
         at Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreRepository`2.GetQueryableAsync()
         at Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.RepositoryAsyncExtensions.SingleAsync[T](IReadOnlyRepository`1 repository, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My Goal:
I want to ensure that the DbContext is correctly registered so that it "automatically" uses the tenant database specified by the Tenant Middleware.
Question:
How can I ensure that the DbContext is correctly registered and managed, so that it uses the tenant's database as configured by the Tenant Middleware? If you need more information to help troubleshoot this issue, please let me know.
